# react js AXIOS authentication fails with network error

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am getting network error while doing axios.post request.

```
axios.post({
    method:'POST',
    url:'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6310',
    withCredentials: true,
    auth: { username: 'username',
            password: 'password'},
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Accept': 'application/json'},
    data :{"jsonrpc":"1.0", "method":"liststreams","params":[]}
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log('res  ------- ',response)
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('error =',error)
  })
```

Thanks,

Comment: what error? cors? bad request?

Comment: Could you add the kind of error you're getting back?

Comment: I am getting 404 error .                                                                                    error = Error: Request failed with status code 404
Stack trace:
createError@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:86124:16
settle@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:86091:13
handleLoad@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:85961:8

Comment: try hitting the route with post man with all your configurations
if it messes up there might be wrong with a. your server or b. your configuration.

Once you confirm it's not the server and everything checksout with postman then reeval your code and read axios docs to see if you followed all the formatting correctly like data types and stuff :)

that's generic help sorry can't really test your route ... haha